# Spring websocket listen to external queue on client side using SockJs

Tags: spring-mvc, activemq-classic, stomp, spring-websocket, sockjs

I have an application that is using spring-websockets and here is the use case

1) User sends a normal HTTP request to the controller(server)

2) The server takes the request and converts it into a message and puts it onto a queue(which has replyTo) and it comes back with request validation successful and I show it on the UI

3) The application that listens to the messages on the queue is a separate application and while it processes the message, it puts the output on another queue in ActiveMQ

4) I am trying to listen to this queue using SockJS on the client side and I do not get any messages.

This is because I am subscribing to the queue in SockJS but I am not actually subscribing as when I look at Active MQ it shows the number of subscribers for that queue is 0.

Can you point me in the right direction as to how to approach this scenario?